# How can I output a table maintaining the same format of the columns perhaps the size of the CLI window

Tags: command-line, bash, formatting

I don't know how much is the title clear, but what I'm trying to do is to print a 3 columns cheat-sheet inside the CLI.

As the window size can be different each time the output is printed, I'd like to find a way to have the same structure (3 columns) each time.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable COLUMNS is updated with width of the current window. Use printf in bash to output padded field widths.

You'll have to do some maths in order to get it looking how you want for all screen widths.